# Collapsing Lemma example gone wrong

Tags: set-theory

I have come across the  [Mostowski collapse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma) and tried applying it to an example came up with to try and understand how it works and it went badly.

For any set $X$ with relation $R$, the transitive collapse of $X$ is the map $\pi$ given by

$\pi (a) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b R a \}$

for $x \in X$.

The lemma says that this map is an isomorphism between $X$ and it's image $\pi (X)$, and this image is transitive.

The example I chose was the power set $X = \mathcal{P}(\{x, y, z\}) = \{ \emptyset, \{x \},  \{y \},  \{z \},  \{x,y \},  \{x,z \},  \{y,z \},  \{x,y,z \} \}$ under the relation of proper subset $\subset$.

So here our collapsing map is given by

$\pi (a) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset a \}$

for $x \in X$.

So I did the following working:

$\pi (\emptyset) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \emptyset \} = \emptyset$

$\pi (\{x\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{x\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset) \} = \{\emptyset\} \\
\pi (\{y\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{y\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset) \} = \{\emptyset\}  \\
\pi (\{z\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{z\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset) \} = \{\emptyset\} $

$\pi (\{x,y\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{x,y\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset), \pi (\{x\}), \pi( \{y\})  \} = \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} $
$\pi (\{x,z\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{x,z\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset), \pi (\{x\}), \pi( \{z\})  \} = \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} $
$\pi (\{y,z\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{y,z\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset), \pi (\{y\}), \pi( \{z\})  \} = \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} $

$\pi (\{x,y,z\}) = \{ \pi (b) \ | \ b \subset \{x,y,z\} \} = \{ \pi (\emptyset), \pi (\{x\}), ..., \pi(\{x,y \}) = \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} \} $.

This image $\pi(X)$ is certainly transitive and corresponds to the von Neumannn ordinal $3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$ but this map cannot be bijective since the cardinality of $|X| = 8$ and the cardinality of the image $| \pi(X) | = 3$.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: This is probably the best way to full understand and appreciate the lemma. Try it out, and figure out why things don't work as expected when they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostowski's lemma says that you can collapse a relation if:

1. It is extensional;
2. it is well-founded; and
3. it is set-like.

Unfortunately, while the inclusion relation on the power set of a finite set is well-founded, it is *not* extensional (in most cases). This case in particular, as you cannot distinguish between different singletons just by asking what are their proper subsets. And you have *three* singletons in your partial order.

Therefore there is no reason to expect the strict inclusion can be collapsed to a transitive set with $\in$.